# VMware: what are the "vpxuser" and "dcui" user accounts for?

Tags: esxi

I am using VMware ESXi 5.1, and apart from the `root` account which I am using to manage my hypervisor, there are two more accounts:

```
vpxuser 
dcui
```

I don't know what these accounts are for, I don't know what the password is. Can I delete them? I am not using vcenter, or any of this stuff. I only need to be able to log in from vSphere client as root.

Is it safe to remove these accounts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vpxuser permission is used for vCenter Server when managing activities for the host.
The account is used as an agent for the Direct Console User Interface and is used is the process for disabling lockdown mode in the DCUI.

you should not delete either account. even though theoretically if you do not use vcenter or direct console ever, you may live without them, but they are so integrated that at least i think their removal is strongly discouraged, unless you just want to experiment and the system is not critical to you.

Comment: thanks. My concern was, since I did not create these accounts, or set the passwords, I don't know what these passwords are. For all I know, these could be some default passwords. Can I at least reset the passwords?

Comment: no, you do not set up anything. these are set up by the system and you should not touch them, period. you do not need to know as these accounts are only for the system, never for humans. as i said, unless you want to see what breaks when you change them, you should leave them alone, other than the case in which you are instructed by vmware tech support.